# Why doesn't the browser give suggestions for this text field?

Tags: html, browser, autocomplete

I have a basic text input for a login form and I'd like the browser to remember email addresses that the user has entered, but it's not working. I don't think I should need to add a full auto-complete system to get this to work since it's something the browser should be doing. I don't see anything special on sites I've visited where this works.

If I search for this problem all the answers are about *disabling* autocomplete.

Here's my login form:

```
<form id="login-form">
  <fieldset>
    <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Your email" required="" >
    <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Pick a good password" required="" minlength="6">
    <button class="login">Register</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: What browsers have you tried (sometimes it's a setting somewhere)?  Also, I think most browsers won't auto-complete on HTTPS.

Comment: I was just testing in Chrome and I don't have autocomplete disabled. I have an example of a site that will do it in https.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the problem here seems to be that I didn't have a "name" attribute on my input. It also seems that I need to have specific values for the name. "email" works and "login" works, but "user_email" and "foo" don't work.

Surprisingly this started working as soon as I added 'name="email"' to the input, so it seems that Chrome was saving the values, but wasn't showing them.

This simple input is all you need for Chrome to do email autocomplete:

```
<input name="email">
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that you can force a user's browser to autocomplete.

HTML5 has an [autocomplete form attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_attributes.asp).

Here is the [W3C spec for autocomplete attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-autocomplete-attribute).

However, even if you set this attribute to "on", the autocomplete of HTML forms is going to depend on the client's browser settings and configuration.

Although you can, as you said, disable *autocomplete*, there is not a way you can force the user's browser to autocomplete a form if they configure their browser not to remember form history.

For example, here is how to disable autocomplete for Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion